# why border bottom is wider than list content?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I  have a list and I want to apply border bottom to it, here is what I want
[image]

here is what I have so far.
[image]

here is jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Mwanitete/vr1c8tgo/10/

```css
.data-right-bottom ul li {
  margin: 10px;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid green;
}

.data-right-bottom ul li span {
  flex: 1 0 0;
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="data-right-bottom">
  <ul>
    <li style="display: none;">
      <span>Total wrapping (tax incl.)</span>
      <span id="total_wrapping_right" class="total_wrapping_right">0,00 zł</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span>Total products (tax incl.)</span>
      <span id="total_product_right" class="total_product_wt_right">210,00 zł</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span>Total shipping (tax incl.)</span>
      <span class="total_shipping_right">
                    
                   12,00 zł
                        
                   </span>
    </li>
    <li class="order-subtotal">
      <span>Total (tax excl.)</span>
      <span class="total_price_without_tax_right">182,73 zł</span>
    </li>
    <li class="order-discounts" style="display:none">
      <span>Total discounts</span>
      <span class="total_discount_right">0,00 zł</span>
    </li>
    <li class="order-tax">
      <span>Total tax</span>
      <span class="total_tax_right">39,27 zł</span>
    </li>
    <li class="order-total">
      <span>Total</span>
      <span class="total_price_right">222,00 zł</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

what am i missing here?  any help will be apreciated

Comment: can you explain what you want briefly

Comment: @moniralhussini I have added the image of what I want, I just want the border should be equal to the list content not wider than it , hope u get it , check the images

Comment: @MrLister is it rensponsive?? as long as rensponsive  will be okay

Comment: don't give a flew grow to the second span, change 'data-right-bottom  ul li span' to .data-right-bottom ul li span:first-child

Comment: @user9964622 In what way should it be responsive? You didn't mention that and your fiddle doesn't give a clue. You can use a media query.

Comment: @MrLister sorry for that, but ur method looks perfect I am checking rensponsiveness,  put it as naswer if goes well I will accept your answer for future reference, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option besides Lazar Nikolic's one is to use a CSS table instead of a flexbox. After all, that's what it is; it displays tabular data.
To make it responsive as you wanted, you can always use a media query to turn it back into a series of blocks so that everything is displayed underneath each other.

```css
.data-right-bottom ul {
  display: table;
}

.data-right-bottom ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: table-row;
}

.data-right-bottom ul li span {
  display: table-cell;
  border-top: 1px solid green;
}

.data-right-bottom ul li span:last-child {
  padding-left: 10px;
  text-align: right;
}

@media all and (max-width: 17em) {
  .data-right-bottom ul li {
    display: block;
    border-top: 1px solid green;
  }
  .data-right-bottom ul li span {
    display: block;
    border-top: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="data-right-bottom">
  <ul>
    <li style="display: none;">
      <span>Total wrapping (tax incl.)</span>
      <span id="total_wrapping_right" class="total_wrapping_right">0,00 zł</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span>Total products (tax incl.)</span>
      <span id="total_product_right" class="total_product_wt_right">210,00 zł</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span>Total shipping (tax incl.)</span>
      <span class="total_shipping_right">
                
               12,00 zł
                    
               </span>
    </li>
    <li class="order-subtotal">
      <span>Total (tax excl.)</span>
      <span class="total_price_without_tax_right">182,73 zł</span>
    </li>
    <li class="order-discounts" style="display:none">
      <span>Total discounts</span>
      <span class="total_discount_right">0,00 zł</span>
    </li>
    <li class="order-tax">
      <span>Total tax</span>
      <span class="total_tax_right">39,27 zł</span>
    </li>
    <li class="order-total">
      <span>Total</span>
      <span class="total_price_right">222,00 zł</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: flex is indeed not the typical display value to use here

Answer (score 1):

The problem is within your css class for 
`.data-right-bottom  ul li span`. Delete it.
Also, under display: flex in `.data-right-bottom  ul li` you should say justify-content: space-between to separate two spans that you have inside. This will give you borders that are as long as your content is. I suppose you used `flex: 1 0 0;` in order for your list to be responsive, but it could not be done considering that you said that the width of your list item should be 400px.

Comment: let me chek that ,

Comment: @LazarNikolic the result of your suggestion is not the same as an expected result on the picture above. The text in the second column of the expected result is aligned to the left, but after your suggestion, it's aligned to the right.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that you're trying to create a table - aren't you? If yes, you should use an HTML table instead of a list.
Especially if you want that the content in the last column has `text-align: left;` but the whole column be aligned to the right border of your block.

List items (`li` inside `ul`) are independent of each other and you can't make one span inside li to have the same variable width depend on the width of the span in other li. Table row, in contrast, changes the width based on its content.

```css
table {
  width: 400px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
   
td {
  border-top:1px solid green;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.price {
  text-align: left;
  width: 1%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="data-right-bottom">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Total products (tax incl.)</td>
      <td class="price">
        210,00 zł
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Total shipping (tax incl.)</td>

      <td class="price">
         12,00 zł
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: @user9964622 I've just updated text-align of the second row so it looks exactly as on your example picture. Not sure if you indeed want to get such alignment but if yes, it's made here.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should change the width of your span to 200px (Span are two inside a "li").

Comment: hii marco that does not work , just try urself u have a link to the jsfiddle to play with it , thanks

Comment: @user9964622 Marco has a good point though; what did you expect to happen by putting two 400px wide spans side by side in a 400px wide container?

Comment: I was trying to solve the issue with different aproach